# Compile a .c programs in CMD like gcc in Terminal Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, windows-vista

What is the preferred way to compile `.c`/`.cpp` files similar to `gcc` (`Linux`) in `cmd` (`Windows`)? What are the most common compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this but it looks like it might be what you're looking for.
http://www.mingw.org/

I think most people use Cygwin.
http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: mingw is easier but doesn't give you all the unix library functions in c, cygwin gives you a completely gnu environment

Comment: This truly is the best option!

Answer (score 0):

Use Dev C++.  From their [site:](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

Bloodshed Dev-C++ is a full-featured Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for the C/C++ programming language. It uses Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) as it's compiler. Dev-C++ can also be used in combination with Cygwin or any other GCC based compiler.

It is a GUI solution, however you can use it from CMD as well.

Another option is to download Cygwin by your self and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The native Windows compiler is Microsoft Visual C++, which also does C89. The Express Edition is free (like no cost, not like open source) to download from here

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

You can use it either from the command line or from the IDE provided in the download.